# Spring JdbcTemplate: how to limit selected rows?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring `JdbcTemplate` interface for fetching data from a MS SqlServer DB.
In the documentation I see there is the `setMaxRows()` method to set a limit for all the queries, but what if I want to limit only a select?

Is there a way to set a limit only for a specific invoked query in a "configurable" way?

Comment: What about using your own PreparedStatementCreator for those statements and call Statement.setMaxRows() when creating the prepared statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that seems a great idea, can you provide me some example of using `PreparedStatementCreator`, I'm new to Spring...

Comment: I'm new to Spring myself, otherwise I would have added an answer with an example :)

Comment: With Spring boot you can use the below property in application.properties              
                                                                                      
         spring.jdbc.template.max-rows=100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limiting the result set of a specific query can be done by putting the limit directly into the query. Consult your DB vendor documentation to see if it supports for example `LIMIT`.

Example on MySQL: `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE LIMIT 10`

Comment: Or `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ROWNUM < 10` in case of Oracle.

Comment: @jabal yes, I know, but in my method implementation, the limit is optional, so, if you have to limit the query directly using SQL, you have to write two different queries...

Comment: In such cases I usually build the query string in my code handling the "limit or no-limit" cases differently and then execute it. I don't know a better solution, curious if someone does.. :-)

Comment: @jabal definitely Burusothman sultion is better - independent of db vendor. If someone use few vendors query customization will be insane.

Comment: spring.jdbc.template.max-rows=100 . Using this property in Spring boot application.properties, you can limit the number of rows.

Answer (score 12):

Some SQL based query languages(**derby**) doesn't support `LIMIT` keyword. So you can't use LIMIT in query directly. Using Spring JDBC Template we can set maximum number of rows needed through `setMaxRows(Integer intvalue)`

```
jdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also user limit keyword in query. see below query

```
select * from FileShare limit 3 offset 3
```

if in your application limit and offset can be assign dynamically by user the  use below query

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate template;

public JdbcTemplate getTemplate() {
    return HibernateUtil.getJdbcTemplate();
}

public List<FileShare> getAllSharedFiless(int limit,int offset)
            throws ShareMeException {
String query="select * from FileShare  limit ? offset ?";
        return getTemplate().query(query,
                new SharedFilesRowMapper(),
                new Object[]{limit,offset});

}
```

Here `FileShare` is a table name and `SharedFilesRowMapper` is rowMapper which list rows from table.

Answer (score 1):

`setFetchSize` or `setMaxRows` is not the same as `LIMIT` in DB SQL. Setting `fetch size` in `JdbcTemplate` means that the resultset of your query will be fetched in chunks of the size set with `setFetchSize`. This is to control the memory usage and the number of database calls.